# How to make Query params array in Angularjs to create only key for all the Elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have been trying to use Query Params in Angularjs and this Query Param in an Array Whenver I try to push elements in this Array the params shows like this

gurugram?rt=shared&rt=independent

How to make this query Params to show only one key like this
gurugram?rt=shared,independent

I have used $location.search('rt', array);

Comment: Instead of pushing to the Query Param Array try appending your new param to the current param value.

Comment: @thinkwinwin I want to use the values in backend Will it affect it/

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it in the backend. You can always split it by "," and then you have the individual values again.

Comment: @thinkwinwin Thank you for your help If you could show me a piece of code it will be really helpful Thank you again